# Include zxing in C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, static-libraries, zxing

I try to integrate zxing in an other C++ project. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 7.

I would like to run the sample code from the zxing repository:
[zxing example](https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp/blob/master/cli/src/main.cpp)

If i compile my project i get an error:

zxing_integration.obj : lnk2001 unresolved external symbol

zxing_integration.exe fatal error lnk1120 1 unresolved external symbol

what I've done so far:

1. create an win32 console application named zxing_integration in the folder ...\workspace
2. create an folder ...\workspace\git and clone the zxing [repository](https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp)
3. create an folder ...\workspace\zxing-cpp\build and build the zxing project with the command line prompt cmake ..\workspace\git\zxing-cpp -G "Visual Studio 11 2012" (i think this step is not necessary)
4. Added under project settings->C/C++ -> additional include directorys (all configurations) the following pathes: ...\workspace\git\zxing-cpp\core\src and ...workspace\git\zxing-cpp\cli\src

After these steps nothing is red underlined or marked in Visual Studio, so i think the source files can be found. If i build the project i get the two errors. i think that the linker needs .lib files, but i can not found zxing libs in the project. Do i have to build the lib files?

It is strange that the error appears in line 258  `source = ImageReaderSource::create(filename);` and not in line 256 `Ref<LuminanceSource> source;`. It seems that `LuminanceSource` can be found.

```
    Ref<LuminanceSource> source;
    try {
        source = ImageReaderSource::create(filename);
    } catch (const zxing::IllegalArgumentException &e) {
        cerr << e.what() << " (ignoring)" << endl;
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling over this dated question: there is a 'new' c++ implementation with lots of improvements compared to the upstream Java project: [ZXingCpp](https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp)

It can be built on Windows/macOS/Linux/Android/WASM.